# The creationComplete event is not triggered in the Button within Itemrenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

There are 2 button columns in my datagrid. I suppose to implement the function 
as described below:
At the beginning, "Compare" button is enabled and "Send" button is disabled. After clicking Compare button, send http request to server, as soon as asynchronous response is returned, make "compare" button disabled and "send" button enabled

To implement this, I use inline Itemrenderer for button column.
There are 2 buttons of "Send" & "Compare" in each line of datagrid shown as below.

[image]

To set the button status in the application level, I defined 2 objects(map) to store the buttons in the datagrid.

```
//for storing send buttons.the key is the first hidden column value "id". 
[Bindable]
public var sendButtonMap:Object = new Object();

//for storing compare buttons.the key is the same as above.
[Bindable]
public var compareButtonMap:Object = new Object();
```

I register the button to the map when button is initializing so that I can control the button outside of the itenrenderer.

```
<mx:Button label="Compare" creationComplete="compareBtn_creationCompleteHandler(event)" />
```

The issue is that the creationComplete is not triggered as the page initializing.
I made the button outside of itemrenderer and it works well.
Why isn't the creationComplete event fired? 
Here list the mxml

```
<s:VGroup xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
          xmlns:configurationIngestSource="configuration.ingestSource.*"
          xmlns:commonComponent="common.*"
          paddingLeft="5"
          paddingTop="5"
          creationComplete="sourceDeviceList_creationCompleteHandler(event);ingestSourceMain_creationCompleteHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            public var sendButtonMap:Object = new Object();
            //Alert.show("init sendButtonMap");
            [Bindable]
            public var compareButtonMap:Object = new Object();
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
<s:DataGrid id="sourceDeviceDataGrid"
            width="{Util.getMainNavigatorWidth() - 27}" 
            height="{Util.getMainNavigatorHeight() / 3 * 2 }"
            selectionMode="singleRow"
            doubleClickEnabled="true"
            dataProvider="{localSourceDevices}">                                
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="id" 
                          headerText="id"
                          visible="false"
                          headerRenderer="{customHeaderRenderer}"/>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="name" 
                          headerText="Name"
                          width="{Util.getMainNavigatorWidth() / 6 }"
                          headerRenderer="{customHeaderRenderer}"/>

            <s:GridColumn dataField="id" 
                          headerText="Compare"
                          width="{Util.getMainNavigatorWidth() / 6 }"
                          headerRenderer="{customHeaderRenderer}">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:GridItemRenderer creationComplete="compareBtn_creationCompleteHandler(event)" >                                  
                            <fx:Script>
                                <![CDATA[
                                    import spark.components.Button;
                                    import mx.events.FlexEvent;
                                    import mx.controls.Alert;

                                    protected function compareBtn_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
                                    {
                                        //Never reach here,anything wrong?
                                        Alert.show(this.data.id);
                                        outerDocument.compareButtonMap[this.data.id] = event.target;
                                    }   

                                ]]>
                            </fx:Script>
                            <mx:Button label="Compare" creationComplete="compareBtn_creationCompleteHandler(event)" />
                        </s:GridItemRenderer>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>

            </s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="id" 
                          headerText="Send"
                          width="{Util.getMainNavigatorWidth() / 6 }"
                          headerRenderer="{customHeaderRenderer}">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:GridItemRenderer>                                        
                            <fx:Script>
                                <![CDATA[

                                    import mx.events.FlexEvent;
                                    import mx.controls.Alert;

                                    protected function sendBtn_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
                                    {

                                        import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
                                        outerDocument.sendButtonMap[this.data.id] = event.currentTarget;
                                        Alert.show( ObjectUtil.toString(event.currentTarget));
                                    }                                                                                                                                       
                                ]]>
                            </fx:Script>
                            <mx:Button label="Send" creationComplete="sendBtn_creationCompleteHandler(event)" />


            </s:GridItemRenderer>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>

            </s:GridColumn>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>            
</s:DataGrid>
</s:VGroup>
```

Comment: What you're doing is bad practice anyway. Back up a bit and say what the end goal you want to accomplish is, and probably some one can help you accomplish _that_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Bindable `isCompared` property to whatever type of object is stored in `localSourceDevices`. Bind the Send button's `enabled` to `isCompared` and the Compare button's `enabled` to `!isCompared`. When the request comes in, change the value of that variable from `false` to `true`.

Comment: @user1744585 Also, from a UX point of view, I don't see the need for two Buttons in two columns. You could just use one Button in one column and simply change its label and click handler according to that `isCompared` boolean.

Comment: @Amy Blankenship your solution is really good. It works now! Thanks.

Comment: @RIAstar Just as you said, actually I had considered that merge 2 buttons into one button, but I need to discuss with the designer first.